# Need help in solving an inequality

Tags: inequality, diophantine-equations, quadratics

The inequality $px^2 + qxy + ry^2 > 0$ should hold true for all possible real values of $x$ and $y$ (both $x$ and $y$ not equal to zero).
How do I find the values of $p$, $q$ and $r$ such that the above condition holds true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: put $y=0,x=1$  to see that $p>0$. Similarly $r>0$. Now write the in equality as $p(x+\frac q {2p}y)^{2}+\frac {4pr-q^{2}} {4p}y^{2}$. Now conclude that the necessary and sufficient conditions are $p>0, r>0$ and $q^{2}<4pr$.

Comment: thank you for your answer ... I'll now work on the question. btw I went through your profile, are you a college professor ? your dp looks like you are a very senior teacher

Comment: I taught Math for 37 years and took retirement to work full time as a student -:).

Comment: Wow that's nice :)

Comment: I want to study equations of this type. Can you please attach links from where I can study more about these equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you know already something about linear algebra and quadratic forms you can proceed as follows:

- $px^2 + qxy + ry^2 = (x\; y)\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}p & \frac{q}{2}\\\frac{q}{2} & r \end{pmatrix}}_{A:=}\begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix}$

Your condition means that $A$ should be **positive definite** which is equivalent to
$$p > 0 \mbox{ and } \det (A) = pr-\frac{q^2}{4} > 0$$.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to report the number of values possible for p, q and r such  that pr - (q/2)^2 is greater than zero ?

Comment: You cannot really report specific number values. But you can report relations between these numbers by distinguishing cases as follows:

$p>0$ can be any positive number.
Now, consider the following two cases: $q=0 \stackrel{p>0, pr>0}{\Rightarrow}r>0$.
$q \neq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{q^2}{4}>0 \stackrel{p>0, pr-\frac{q^2}{4}>0}{\Rightarrow}r >  \frac{q^2}{4p}$.
So, for any $p>0$ you can find infinitely many $r$ such that your quadratic expression is positive for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I want to study equations of this type. Can you please attach links from where I can study more about these equations.

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi :maybe you can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form